# Is there anyway to take an opencv display window and save it to a GUI window?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

Just a general question. Instead of having a popup window appear when I use imshow, is it possible to have this window open up in a GUI application (could be any GUI framework, I am just wondering if this is possible) view instead?

Comment: Sure, save the image to a temporary name on disk and use `os.system()` to start MS-Paint or somesuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have done this in an older project. I used Qt with c++ and converted like this:

```
QPixmap UIQT::pixmapFromMat(cv::Mat src) {
    QImage image(this->imageFromMat(src));
    return QPixmap::fromImage(image);
}

QImage UIQT::imageFromMat(cv::Mat src) {
    Q_ASSERT(src.type() == CV_8UC3);
    return QImage((uchar*)src.data, src.cols, src.rows, 
        src.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
}
```

It was quite neat to use Qt with opencv, but it is some years ago since I last did this and I guess it is even easier now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to design a Window-based application using highgui, the same api that you use for displaying pop-up windows. But I am not sure how powerful it is, when it comes to designing a fully fledged application.

If you are using python, *pyqt* is generally easy to work with. For c++, you have choices like Qt (multiplatform), Quartz (Mac, with Objective C or Swift), etc.